# sub folder hiding from wordpress multisite htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, multisite

I have to hide a folder from a URL. Means if URL is `example.com/testing/folder/index.php` I want to access same `index.php` but URL should be
`example.com/folder/index.php`.

So basically I need to remove **testing** from the URL.

I am getting it to work by following:

Goes in **DOCUMENT_ROOT/testing/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+testing([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Goes in **DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^/?testing testing%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

But the problem is I am using wordpress multisite when I use this the multisite stops and gives error:

```
" Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document. "
```

URL is something like `http://www.example.com`. 
Can any body help regarding this?

I am defining these rules on top of my **htaccces** above all this code after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```